# Search a and replace b in a b substring

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a very large hosts file on my Linux machine:

```
1.1.1.1  hostA hosta
1.1.1.2  hostB hostb
1.1.1.3  hostC hostc
1.1.1.4  hostD hostd
1.1.1.5  hostE hoste
1.1.1.6  hostF hostf
1.1.1.7  hostG hostg
.......
```

And I have the lines I want to modify in `file2`:

```
2.1.1.1 hostA hosta
2.1.1.2 hostB hostb 
2.1.1.3 hostC hostc
```

So, the desired output is:

```
2.1.1.1  hostA hosta
2.1.1.2  hostB hostb
2.1.1.3  hostC hostc
1.1.1.4  hostD hostd
1.1.1.5  hostE hoste
1.1.1.6  hostF hostf
1.1.1.7  hostG hostg
.......
```

I know how to use like the one below:

```
sed '/hostA/ s/1.1.1.1/2.1.1.1/' hosts
```

But I don't know how to use it in a `for` loop. Or there is another, faster way to modify hosts?

Comment: how large is "very large", as in, number of lines according to `wc -l /etc/hosts`? ("very large" is a very relative term. Few people agree on what it means, and it does make a difference here on how to solve your problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Muller.      wc -l /etc/hosts     1832 /etc/hosts

Comment: Please don't multi-post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74687950/1745001

Answer (score 2):

The following is using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the files as header-less "pretty-printed" data and then perform a left-join operation between the `hosts` file and the `new` file, using the 2nd and 3rd fields on each line as the join key.

```bash
$ mlr --pprint -N join -j 2,3 -f hosts --ul then reorder -f 1,2,3 new
2.1.1.1 hostA hosta
2.1.1.2 hostB hostb
2.1.1.3 hostC hostc
1.1.1.4 hostD hostd
1.1.1.5 hostE hoste
1.1.1.6 hostF hostf
1.1.1.7 hostG hostg
```

The `reorder` operation at the end reorders the fields in the same order as they were found in the input (we would otherwise get the last two fields as fields 1 and 2 for parts of the data).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 2 GNU sed invocations, e.g.:

```
sed -E 's:([^ ]+) +(.*):/\2/ s/^[^ ]+/\1/:' file2 |
sed -Ef - hosts
```

The first `sed` generates a new sed-script:

```
/hostA hosta/ s/^[^ ]+/2.1.1.1/
/hostB hostb/ s/^[^ ]+/2.1.1.2/
/hostC hostc/ s/^[^ ]+/2.1.1.3/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ip[$2]=$1; next} $2 in ip{$1=ip[$2]} 1' file2 hosts
2.1.1.1 hostA hosta
2.1.1.2 hostB hostb
2.1.1.3 hostC hostc
1.1.1.4 hostD hostd
1.1.1.5 hostE hoste
1.1.1.6 hostF hostf
1.1.1.7 hostG hostg
```

or if you care abut preserving white space between fields:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ip[$2]=$1; next} $2 in ip{sub(/[0-9.]+/,ip[$2])} 1' file2 hosts
```

If you actually need to use both host names from each line as a key rather than just `$2` as in your example then just change every `$2` to `($2,$3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the lazy way with a single `sed` run:

```
sed -E '1,/^$/{H;d;};G;s/^([0-9.]*)([[:space:]]*)([[:print:]]*)(\n.*\n)([0-9.]*)([[:space:]]*)\3/\5\2\3\4/;P;d' file2 <(echo) /etc/hosts
```

This is collecting `file2` lines in hold space, appending them to each line of the hosts file as lookup table, and using backreferences to replace the IP.

Probably easier to write than to read, as often with regular expressions.

Answer (score -3):

As a variant:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 file2 > hostids
$ grep -v -f hostids hosts > newhosts
$ cat file2 >> newhosts
$ sort -t' ' -k2 newhosts > hosts
```

Comment: This will consider `hostABC` as a match for `hostA`.